# Installation path for root

Tags: linux, path

My understanding of paths is that `~/.jungledisk/` means the path is relative to the current user.  If that's true, if I installed this as root, where did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure: in case you install as root, that folder could be also created under /root, I mean, /root/.jungledisk, and its permission and owner would be unavailable for other users.

Anyway, when some program asks you to "make install" as root, it does knowing that the installation will copy binaries on folders that are only writable by root. But users will be able to use that utilities (read and execute them, not write/edit/delete them), so there should be no problem.

Don't know if I 've understood the problem, but there it goes :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the same, unless the installation special-cases root, in which case who knows.

Comment: But root doesn't have a `/home/` folder, are you saying it would go to `/`?

Comment: @Webnet: No, it would go to `~root`.

Comment: @Webnet, Root's home directory is typically /root/ on Linux boxes.

Answer (score 0):

"~" is magically expanded to the actual home directory of the following user.  You can find out what root's (or any user's) home directory like this:

```
echo ~root
```